# Powershell Import-CSV from SharePoint

Tags: powershell, csv, import

Is there a way to import a CSV from a Website and use it in PowerShell? With the `Import-Csv` Cmdlet I get this error:

```
$FilePath = "http://sharepoint.com/mydocuments/serverlist.csv"
$serverList = Import-Csv $FilePath -Delimiter ";"


Import-Csv : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'http' does not exist.
At line:2 char:15
+ $serverList = Import-Csv $FilePath -Delimiter ";"
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (http:String) [Import-Csv], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvCommand
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the CSV first:

```powershell
$FilePath = "http://sharepoint.com/mydocuments/serverlist.csv"
$localPath = "C:\temp\serverlist.csv"
$wc = New-Object System.Net.Webclient
$wc.DownloadFile($FilePath, $localPath)
$serverList = Import-Csv $localPath -Delimiter ";"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Make sure you add your headers if you don't already have them or remove header option if you do):

```
#Create an array 
$serverList= @()
#Create URL Variable
$FilePath= "http://sharepoint.com/mydocuments/serverlist.csv"
#ImportData from URL and use convert-FromCSV into Array
$serverList = (Invoke-WebRequest $FilePath).content | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delim ';' -Header 'header1','header2'
```